# Get QClipboard changes when my window is not activated

Tags: qt, qt5

**QClipboard** can get text when window is activated, such as

```
connect(QApplication::clipboard(), SIGNAL(dataChanged()),
        this, SLOT(clipboard_datachanged()));
```

but my application is on the system tray, so when the window is not activated, i can't get the clipboard signal of **dataChanged**, so i want to get text from clipperboard when my window is not activated

Comment: Just to be sure, which OS are you on?

Comment: i want to support windows, mac, linux

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MacOS, [you can't](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#dataChanged). On Windows, it seems to work fine for me.

> On macOS and with Qt version 4.3 or higher, clipboard changes made by
> other applications will only be detected when the application is
> activated.

Comment: can i write a dylib in mac to support this feature?

Comment: https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/94931/12/src/plugins/platforms/cocoa/qcocoaclipboard.mm. It seems to me that the signal is only emitted once the window is activated. I don't think a dylib can change that behavior in Qt.

Comment: @Minh in 2022 (almost) is there a solution or is it still unsolved? I am facing this currently: https://github.com/nodegui/nodegui/discussions/902#discussioncomment-1877629

Comment: I don't think so, [Qt6.2 documentation](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qclipboard.html#dataChanged) is still the same